# simplejson not escaping single quote on app engine server

Tags: javascript, python, simplejson

I'm trying to generate a properly formatted json object to use in javascript. I've tried simplejson.dumps(string), but it behaves differently on my local machine (in the python shell) vs. on the server (running google app engine).  For example, locally i'll get:

```
>>> s= {u'hello': u"Hi, i'm here"}
>>> simplejson.dumps(s)
'{"hello": "Hi, i\'m here"}'
```

which all looks good.  But when i run it on the server, I get

{"hello": "Hi, i'm here"}

where the single quote is not escaped, which throws an error in my javascript.

Short of doing a secondary `string.replace("'", r"\'")`, does anyone have suggestions?  I'm at a loss and have already spent waay to much time trying to figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are being confused by the `repr` behaviour vs the actual output.

```
>>> s= {u'hello': u"Hi, i'm here"}
>>> simplejson.dumps(s)
'{"hello": "Hi, i\'m here"}'
>>> print simplejson.dumps(s)
{"hello": "Hi, i'm here"}
```

When you simply ask for the result of the simplejson call, the Python shell prints that result using `repr` - which escapes it so that you can cut and paste it back in later. However, there isn't actually a backslash in the string produced by `dumps`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no escape needed for single quotes in JSON, and in fact there's no backslash in the string returned in your example:

```
>>> print simplejson.dumps(s)
{"hello": "Hi, i'm here"}
```

So I suspect that your javascript error is something else.

Comment: Thanks! I think i understand the problem now... I was assuming that simplejson.dumps() would escape single quotes, and so when jquery tried to handle the output *without* escaped single quotes it thought the json string ended before it actually does.  ie: jQuery.parseJSON('{"hello": "Hi, i'm here"}); was being interpreted as jQuery.parseJSON({"hello": "Hi, i'  which was giving me a "missing )" error.